# How do I filter out large variances from my average calc in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to calculate the average while dropping several large outliers shown here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDk9q.png)

This is my average calc

```
Average = AVERAGEX( 
                 VALUES(
                       Matched_JobID, 
                       ), 
                 [Job_duration_Variance])
```

This is what I have tried so far but with no luck.

```
Average = AVERAGEX( 
                 VALUES( Filter(
                       Matched_JobID, 
                       [Job_duration_Variance]< 100)
                 ), 
          [Job_duration_Variance])
```

I am thinking it might be better to filter the average measure

> Average =
> VAR avg1.......
> filter(avg1))

But idk how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps something equivalent to Excel's `TRIMMEAN` function would be appropriate. But I'm guessing this would be more easy to implement in Power Query vs DAX.

Comment: What is the table name?  `Matched_JobID`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Average = AVERAGEX( 
                 Filter(
                       Matched_JobID, 
                       [Job_duration_Variance] < 100)
                 ), 
                 [Job_duration_Variance]
          )
```

It will help you get the average measure while filtering.